# login является undefind. Роут не видит логин

Tags: reactjs, axios

Прошу помочь, организовал такой запрос в базу, передал в клиентскую функцию аргумент, которая передаст его дальше на сервер, но auth.router.js не может поймать login. Ломаю голову уже второй час.

P.S Разворачиваю массив с объектами в компоненте через map, и только тогда он выводит ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

Буду благодарен за ответ

HistoryPage.jsx:

```
const login = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser.login);
  
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getEarned(login))
}, [])
```

user.js:

```
export const getEarned = (login) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/history',
                login
            )
            dispatch(calcEarn(response.data.orders))
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

auth.router.js:

```
router.post('/history', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const {login} = req.body    

        var date = new Date()
        var dateOrder = `${date.getDate()}.${date.getMonth()+1}.${date.getFullYear()}`

        const finishOrders = await Order.find({dateOrder, complete: "finish", whoTake: login})
        res.json({finishOrders})
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в том, что я забыл засунуть login в объект при получении.

```
export const getEarned = (login) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/history', {
                login
            })
            dispatch(calcEarn(response.data.orders))
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Должно получиться вот так. Сергею спасибо, в дальнейшем буду указывать больше информации